# How to combine a string and a variant of the body of an email in vba

Tags: excel, vba, sendmail, type-mismatch

I have the following code and get a Mismatch 13 Error when debugging:

finalbody = body1 & body2

```
olMail.Body = finalbody
olMail.Display
```

Where body1 is a string and body2 is a variant (data that is like an image in a spreadsheet).

Can anyone help me solve this error in order to send an email? I know it doesn't show the full code but it isn't necessary I think.

Comment: The full code is always necessary. If you want help please post all the relevant information.

Comment: I think you need special treatment of non-textual content. Google hint:  `vba send mail with embedded image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the variant to string: CStr(variant variable name) or convert the string to variant CVar(string variable name)

Either

```
 finalbody = CVar(body1) & body2
```

Or

```
finalbody = body1 & CStr(body2)
```